# How to propagate module augmentation of custom MUI theme inside a component library monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui

In my company, we're building a monorepo of component libraries (no app). In our **core** package, we're exporting a custom MUI theme with custom brand options (using module augmentation, as per the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/#typescript)), intended to be used in consumer apps to normalize the company branding and styles all throughout our applications.

In another package of the monorepo (let's call it **foo**), we have a library that exports several components that uses MUI styled components internally, which should make use of our custom MUI theme, since that's the intended way for them to be used.

However, because **foo** package itself doesn't have a direct dependency to the **core** package, and because there's no app or `ThemeProvider` involved here, typescript isn't able to guess the custom theme structure we are exporting in the **core** package, and defaults to the default MUI properties. This means that the following code **throws a TS error**:

```js
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const Root = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey.light4, // TS2339: Property light4 does not exist on type Color
}));
```

Is there any way to **safeguard** this and/or propagate the module augmentation of the **core** package to the **foo** package, even if there's no direct code dependency?